# Restoring Server 2008 Enterprise AD backups on Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I want to take a backup of Active directory on a Server 2008 Enterprise system and restore it on a Server 2008 R2 Domain Controller.

Is this possible?
Are there any issues with schema differences between 2008 Enterprise and 2008 R2?

Comment: Introduce the new server as a Domain Controller in the existing domain. Then demote the old server.

Answer (score 7):

Bring up your Server 2008 R2 machine, and dcpromo it to the existing 2008 domain. Once that is done, transfer all the roles and demote and remove the old server.

Comment: As an aside, running DCPROMO to demote the old DC will gracefully transfer the FSMO roles to the new DC.

Comment: @joeqwerty It still bothers my delicate sensibilities that you run `dcpromo` to *demote* domain controllers. Microsoft should really rename it `dctool` or `dcutil` or something.

Comment: DCDEPROMO...DCUNPROMO... DCNOPROMO? :)